# Invalid syntax ncdump for netcdf python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, netcdf4

I'm trying to access a NASA TRMM dataset through netcdf. However, after installing various packages, I still get stuck on ncdump, which I need to analyse the structure of the data in the given file (following [this example](http://schubert.atmos.colostate.edu/~cslocum/netcdf_example.html)) . I'm running it on jupyter notebook and my code is as follows:

```
import gdal
import urllib
import netCDF4 as nc
import datetime as dt #Python standard library datetime module
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, addcyclic, shiftgrid
url = 'https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov:443/opendap/TRMM_L1/TRMM_1B11/2015/001/1B11.20150101.97563.7.HDF';
ncfile = nc.Dataset(url, "r");
ncdump -k ncfile
```

Resulting in a Syntax Error (invalid syntax). Any tips or advice?

Comment: `ncdump -k` is a shell command syntax, for Python you have to follow through the example defining the `ncdump()` function and using it accordingly. You should not mix shell and Python syntax.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, define the expected output in the most specific way possible.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm trying to review the structure of the data in the given url, so I can explore the dataset without downloading it completely and later use it to specifically access and download certain variables in it (e.g. data in a certain timeframe). Following the given example, I would need to use ncdump as a function (in the example: (`def ncdump (nc_fid, verb=True):`). Since this isn't working, first, I'm going back to the basics of how to work with ncdump.